# OpenCV java get pixel color

Tags: java, opencv

I made the following Java program:

```
 System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
 Mat image = Highgui.imread("lena.png");

 Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
 byte buff[] = new byte[ (int) (image.total() * image.channels())];

 int a;
 int b;
 int picdata[][] =  new int[10][10] ;

 for (a=0 ; a<10;a++){
     for (b=0 ; b<10;b++){
        picdata[a][b]=  image.get(a, b,buff);    

     }
 }
```

When I look at picdata, I receive a numbers:

```
"picdata"    (id=24)    
    [0] (id=25) 
        [0] 225 
        [1] 224 
        [2] 223 
        [3] 222 
        [4] 221 
    [1] (id=27) 
        [0] 210 
        [1] 209 
        [2] 208 
               ............
```

If I check for `image.get(x,y)`, I receive the required number (between 0 and 255) but I don't know how to write it into the picdata.

How do I alter the code to fill picdata with grayscale data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem was finally solved through:

```
 byte buff[] = new byte[ (int) (image.total() * image.channels())];

 int a;
 int b;
 double picdata[][] =  new double[10][10] ;
 double[] temp;

 for (a=0 ; a<10;a++){
     for (b=0 ; b<10;b++){
         temp=   image.get(a, b);
         picdata[a][b]=temp[0]; 

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've no experience in using OpenCV in Java, but this code should work fine:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
 Mat image = Highgui.imread("lena.png");

 Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
 int a;
 int b;
 int picdata[][] =  new int[10][10] ;

 for (a=0 ; a<10;a++){
     for (b=0 ; b<10;b++){
        picdata[a][b]= (int) image.get(a, b);    

     }
 }
```

Note that `picdata` is an array on `int`, but other arrays in your code are arrays of `byte`. Did you intended that?

Comment: Hi, sadly I still receive an error in the line  `code` picdata[a][b]= (int) image.get(a, b);           it says cannot cast from double[] to int. I intend to fill a matrix with the rgb or grayscale value of the image  for further processing